# Integrate RequireJS in existing AngularJS structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

**Existing AngularJS Structure**

[image: Existing structure]

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- JQuery Library -->
<script src="assets/js/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Libraries -->
<script src="assets/js/lib/Angular/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/Angular/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.route.js"></script>

<!-- Demo Module Files -->
<script src="modules/demo/demoMod.js"></script>
<script src="modules/demo/services/demoService.js"></script>
<script src="modules/demo/controllers/demoController.js"></script>
<script src="modules/demo/filters/demoFilters.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ul><li><a href="#/appcustomfilter">Application Specific Custom Filter Example</a></li></ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.route.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','demoModule','app-custom-filters']);
myApp.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/appcustomfilter', {
             templateUrl : 'modules/demo/views/app-custom-filter.html',
             controller : 'demoCtrl'
            });
    }]);
```

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['demoModule']);
```

Module folder structure

[image: Mod structure]

**modules/demo/demoMod.js**

```
angular.module('demoModule',[
   'demoModule.controllers' ,
   'demoModule.services',
   'demoModule.filters'
]);
```

How do I integrate AngularJS and RequireJS for above structure ? I have tried using [this](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home) but it works for a seed structrue. I need to load module code only when its called.

Answer (score 0):

Try System.js https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs with ES6 modules https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/es6-modules-overview.md

It create single file that you connect to your html page, and include to this file only modules that you need to call.